# It's 2014, is there an elegant way to insert loads of rows of data yet?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, entity-framework, ado.net

I receive loads of data from a 3rd party's web service and ingesting it into our database.

The amount of data will represent 100,000s rows, will run nightly and needs processing on the application server before inserting/merging into my sql db. A few options for mass inserts spring to mind.

1. Entity Framework - takes far too long as it seems to send the insert commands one at a time!
2. StringBuilder and a SqlCommand - sounds better
3. Send an XML serialization of the List of the objects I want inserted to a stored procedure that uses nodes() to get all the values to INSERT/MERGE.

I've always preferred number 3 and used it many times but it still seems unpleasant and doesn't seem well know on the internetz so was wondering if there is a new or standard way that everyone else gets around this problem.

I use the .NET stack btw.

Comment: Did you try one of the tools available for data loading like BULK INSERT, bcp, SSIS? They've been there for a very long time and can handle millions of rows in minutes. The options you mentioned are actually considered bad practices

Comment: Can you please point me to somewhere that discusses why the XML way is considered practice. I am interested as I am still using it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've recently been looking at this. I initially used a SqlBulkCopy to store it all in a DataTable and send it up that way.

The problem was with the receiving table needing to be empty so it was memory intensive.

I used Table Value Parameters (SQL 2008) in the end.

Comment: You can use a DataReader with SqlBulkCopy to preserve memory

Comment: But I was still sat with a huge datatable in memory while the datareader is feeding the SqlBulkCopy, thats the problem I was having. Or have I misguessed where the datareader fits in. Got any links?

Comment: You can feed SqlBulkCopty with a DataReader instead of a dataTable, thus saving memory, as DataReader is streamed

Comment: I was downloading a few mil rows into specific text files then uploading them to SQL. I didn't realise I could point the DataReader directly to the text files. I guess OleDbConnection?

Comment: No, there are libraries that can read csv files and expose them as a DbDataReader, like http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader

Answer (score 1):

You can do bulk insert by using [Table Valued parameters](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/31/sql-server-table-valued-parameters-in-sql-server-2008/) in sqlServer 2008 and above;

Comment: Pretty sure TVP didn't turn up till 2008